# ECHO results of a "join" query

Tags: php

I am not being successful display the results of a query.  I checked the query using mysql client in terminal and the data is there as I would like.  However, I don't seem to be able to get the php correct for displaying the data.  I want username and underneath the username comment_copy for all rows.  This is the coding I got from the php manual but it does not work.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
$query2 = "SELECT u.username, c.comment_copy FROM comments AS c
           INNER JOIN userlogin AS u USING (user_id) 
           WHERE blog_id = 1 AND c.comment_archived = 0"; 
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

if(!$result2)  die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
/*$contents = mysql_num_rows($result2);*/


while ($content = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)); {
    echo $content['username'] ;
    echo $content['comment_copy'];
```

Comment: Well, first of all, `enter code here` is a syntax error...

Comment: is anything being echo'd out? try echo "username: " . $content['username']; and see if you can see the "username: " part

Comment: Also, the `mysql_` extensions have been deprecated in PHP 5.5, and are just generally not as safe to use. Try PDO or MySQLi and prepared statements instead - they're really nice!

Answer (score 2):

```
while ($content = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)); {
```

This is an empty loop, followed by a block; so all the rows will be read and have nothing done with them, and then you'll try to `echo` values from `false`, which doesn't do anything. Take out the semicolon:

```
while ($content = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
```

Comment: Okay I get the data but my format is not right.  I need for it to look like this.  record 1  username then underneath comment then record 2 etc

Comment: Sorry, I need it in a format where for each record, I get the username and underneath the comment.  Then move to the next record.  A blog if you will.

Comment: @Learner: `echo $content['username'] ;` -> `echo $content['username'], '<br />';`?

Comment: I got it figured out:echo "$content[username] <br /> $content[comment_copy]";